# RSpec naming conventions for files and directory structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing RSpec tests and I have come to a point where I am not reading the same opinions on different websites.  The directory structure for RSpec is clear when we are dealing with spec/controllers and spec/models directories, but the conflicting information I am getting deals with testing views.

I would like to just put these tests in a spec/integration/ directory, but I have read that it's supposed to be under spec/integration, but another book says spec/requests.  Does this matter?

To further complicate the situation, I have read conflicting information on naming the actual file names of the tests!  For example, if I had a controller/model/view directory called 'people' (I i use haml), I should name the files like this:

> spec/integration/people.html.haml_spec.rb

However, another book suggests this:

> spec/requests/people_spec.rb

I would like a little explanation of naming conventions within RSpec and WHY I should name the view tests specific names, as well as whether or not it matters to put them under spec/integration or spec/requests.  I feel like I'm going with the wind here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the dates of the books and the versions of RSpec for which they were written. The naming structure has changed slightly over time.

According to the docs for [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails), request specs can go in spec/requests, spec/api, or spec/integration. I prefer to put request specs in spec/requests.

To make things more interesting, if you are using [Capybara](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/Capybara.md) with rspec-rails, it will work with spec/requests for Capybara 1.x, and spec/features for Capybara 2.

As to individual spec file names, when there is a specific class under test, like a Rails model, you should use an analogous spec file name:

`app/models/user.rb` -> `spec/models/user_spec.rb`

View specs should use the template name:

`app/views/users/index.html.erb` -> `spec/views/users/index.html.erb_spec.rb`

Namespaced models should include the namespace in the spec file path:

`app/models/admin/user.rb` -> `spec/models/admin/user_spec.rb`

The RSpec scaffold generator is a good guide for showing where these specs belong.

When there is no specific class under test, as is the case with request specs, IMHO you should feel free to use a name that describes the thing being tested. E.g. `spec/requests/place_an_order_spec.rb`.

Comment: Shouldn't view specs be formatted `spec/views/user.html.erb_spec.rb` instead of `spec/views/user.html.erb`? Also, `spec/views/user.html.erb` seems like a strange example, wouldn't `spec/views/users/index.html.erb` make more sense?

Comment: Guys! What if I want to have two spec files for single model? For example: first for scopes and second for some logic... Any suggestions? `user_scopes_spec.rb` and `user_my_feature_name_spec.rb`?

Answer (score 2):

The files read by the rspec gem are simply those that end in `_spec.rb` and that are anywhere in the hierarchy below the `spec` folder as long as the top of the hierarchy is an alpha-numeric word (that is, files under a folder named `spec/##/` would not be considered in generating specs.) This is the relevant line of code that implements this, in `/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.1/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake`:

```
namespace :spec do
  types = begin
    dirs = Dir['./spec/**/*_spec.rb'].
           map { |f| g=f.sub(/^\.\/(spec\/\w+)\/.*/, '\\1') ; puts ">>> Found #{g}."; g }.
           uniq.
           select { |f| File.directory?(f) }
    Hash[dirs.map { |d| [d.split('/').last, d] }]
  end
```

So all the text in the filename previous to `_spec.rb` is a convention - it doesn't change how Rails processes the files.

I'd have to read through the code a lot more to figure out what the significance of each folder name, under `spec`, is - it gets passed through to the Rake spec task that's created, so it's being used for *something* but I don't know what.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the file selection. Depending on the directory, different helpers are loaded. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure