# what changes to be made in spec_helper.rb to run my specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, specifications

i want to restructure my spec folder to something like below :

```
-spec
  -unit
    -Controller
      -example.rb
    -model
  -Integration
    -controller
    -model
```

What changes i have to make in my spec_helper.rb to run my specs in /spec/unit/controller/example.rb file.?

Has anybody ever tried restructuring specs based upon their high level like unit/integration etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change anything in your `spec_helper.rb`. You do, however, need to change `example.rb` to [`example_spec.rb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22186087/1120015)

> This is the relevant line of code that implements this, in
>   `/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.1/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake`:
>
> ```
> namespace :spec do
>   types = begin
>     dirs = Dir['./spec/**/*_spec.rb'].
>            map { |f| g=f.sub(/^\.\/(spec\/\w+)\/.*/, '\\1') ; puts ">>> Found #{g}."; g }.
>            uniq.
>            select { |f| File.directory?(f) }
>     Hash[dirs.map { |d| [d.split('/').last, d] }]
>   end
> ```
>
> So all the text in the filename previous to _spec.rb is a convention -
>   it doesn't change how Rails processes the files.

---

To run only some of your specs, you could filter them in the command line by [tags](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/command-line/tag-option) or by [text](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/example-option), or simply by giving the wanted root dir:

```sh
rspec . --example controller # only runs tests which have the word 'controller' in them
rsepc . --tag model # only runs tests which are tagged as 'model' => true
rspec ./spec/unit # only runs specs which are under ./spec/unit
```

Comment: what changes i need to make to run my different group of specs? For ex : If i just want to run specs under ./spec/unit directory then what changes are required?

Comment: Added examples for selecting which specs to run

Comment: I copied my original spec/controller/example_controller_spec.rb to spec/unit/controller/example_controller_spec.rb and when i executed bundle exec rspec spec/unit/controller/example_controller_spec.rb  it is failing with error 'undefined method for Sinatra::Application:Class'

Comment: do you require 'sinatra' in the spec_helper? do you require 'spec_helper' is the spec?

Comment: yes.. i require my spec_helper in spec. what i want to understand is - same spec runs if it's under spec/controller but it failes when it is under spec/unit/controller. what could be the possible reason?

Comment: perhaps you need to require_relative: `require_relative '../../spec_helper.rb'`